# Why was my flag (too localized) on my own question declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I asked this question a while back: [Why do I get an Access Violation in atio6axx.dll when calling glBindBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13433071/1751715)

I ended up never finding the answer, but I rewrote most of it with some help and the problem disappeared. I wasn't sure what to do with the question at the time, so I left it.

Coming back to it months later, I couldn't see how anyone would benefit from it (and even I didn't), so I voted to close it. It was declined with "no evidence to support it."

Why would (should) this question remain open? How can I give evidence that it should be closed?

Comment: You put a lot of effort in the question - why should it be closed? Someone might answer it someday if not closed.

Comment: Right but none of it led to an answerable question. I *still* have no idea what the problem was (though I speculate it was me not knowing a damn thing about WinAPI and window creation), and it disappeared with a rewrite. Granted, if it's true that it will eventually be answered that's awesome, and I'll agree that it should stay open.

Comment: That problem could happen to other people. Could be a bug in the framework.

Comment: As the OP you should be able to cast close votes on your own questions; you can cast the first vote, it will appear in 10K user tools and if others agree they will add their vote too. No need to involve a moderator.

Comment: Really? I couldn't see any close option. I'll look again. Where would I see it?

Comment: @Alex: below the tags, right next to the edit and flag links.

Comment: Ah, that requires 250 rep, sorry forgot about that (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes). The close link would appear between the edit and delete links. I just cast a vote "on your behalf".

Comment: @Mat Thanks. Is flagging my only option until 250?

Comment: Alex yes only flagging until you reach 250, but I tend to agree with @juergend that it shouldn't be closed in the first place.

Comment: @Alex: asking for support on meta works too, especially if you're not sure what to do. Some chat rooms are also quite busy with people of with all sorts of rep who can either give you advice or use their privileges to help out.

Comment: Ok. Sounds good. I'll check chat next time too. Thanks for your help.